# Java use AIML with AB program

Tags: java, aiml

I am trying to write a chatbot with java. I've already download AB program from https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/downloads

However, when I try to write code in IntelliJ, it always shows error like this:
[image]

Here is what I put in my package: 
**Do I miss anything??**
Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: You've not added Program AB's lib in your project or maybe the version is not correct

Comment: I've added lib outside the src file, but I just move lib into src file, it still has errors.  Where can I find the latest version? I download it from https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab/downloads, I think its already the latest version (?!)

Comment: Oh! I just use Open Moduel Settings and put it into Libraries, and it works! Thank you!!

Comment: Sure! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not have added the Program AB's lib in your project. Ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project) for adding it and it should work.

Also, make sure that the lib show up in `External Libraries`